# Return empty dataframe when reading KML file of 'Sentinel 1 Acquisition Segments' using GeoPandas

Tags: python, kml, geopandas, sentinel-1

I have downloaded the KML file of 'Sentinel 1 Acquisition Segments' from this [url](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-1/observation-scenario/acquisition-segments). I have written this code to read KML file into GeoDataFrame, but the code returns empty GeoDataFrame.

```
>>>import fiona
>>>import geopandas as gpd
>>> gpd.__version__
'0.8.1'
>>> fiona.__version__
'1.8.17'
>>>gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'
>>>fp = 'Sentinel-1A_MP_20201006T160000_20201026T180000.kml'
>>>gdf = gpd.read_file(fp, driver='KML')
>>>gdf
Empty GeoDataFrame
Columns: [Name, Description, geometry]
Index: []
```

Is there any code that I missed, or should I have to manipulate the KML file before?

Comment: @BERA, is the path too long or contain an invalid character? Fyi, I used the relative path.

Comment: Its not a valid path to the file. For example `r"C:\somefolder\Sentinel-1A_MP_20201006T160000_20201026T180000.kml"` could be valid. Python does not know where the file is

Comment: I have done on that way, but it returned same result (empty). I assume that the KML contains multiple folders, and I have done by using fiona listlayers method 
by the following answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/328554/133557, but it returned empty as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I fixed the issue inspired by the following answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/328554/133557, I changed the driver to 'LIBKML', so the final code as following:

```
import fiona
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['LIBKML'] = 'rw'

fp = 'Sentinel-1A_MP_20201006T160000_20201026T180000.kml'

gdf_list = []
for layer in fiona.listlayers(fp):
    if 'S1' in layer:
        gdf = gpd.read_file(fp, driver='LIBKML', layer=layer)
        gdf_list.append(gdf)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat(gdf_list, ignore_index=True))
```

Result:

[image]